# Element of shared_array as shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

If I have a `boost::shared_array<T>` (or a `boost::shared_ptr<T[]>`), is there a way to obtain a `boost::shared_ptr<T>` which shares with the array?

So for example, I might want to write:

```
shared_array<int> array(new int[10]);
shared_ptr<int> element = &array[2];
```

I know that I can't use `&array[2]`, because it just has type `int *`, and it would be dangerous for `shared_ptr<int>` to have an implicit constructor that will take that type. Ideally `shared_array<int>` would have an instance method on it, something like:

```
shared_ptr<int> element = array.shared_ptr_to(2);
```

Unfortunately I can't find anything like this. There is an aliasing constructor on `shared_ptr<int>` which will alias with another `shared_ptr<T>`, but it won't allow aliasing with `shared_array<T>`; so I can't write this either (it won't compile):

```
shared_ptr<int> element(array, &array[2]);
//Can't convert 'array' from shared_array<int> to shared_ptr<int>
```

Another option I played with was to use `std::shared_ptr<T>` (`std` instead of `boost`). The specialisation for `T[]` isn't standardised, so I thought about defining that myself. Unfortunately, I don't think that's actually possible in a way that doesn't break the internals of the aliasing constructor, as it tries to cast my `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` to its own implementation-specific supertype, which is no longer possible. (Mine is currently just inheriting from the boost one at the moment.) The nice thing about this idea would have been that I could implement my instance `shared_ptr_to` method.

Here's another idea I experimented with, but I don't think it's efficient enough to be acceptable as something we're potentially going to use throughout a large project.

```
template<typename T>
boost::shared_ptr<T> GetElementPtr(const boost::shared_array<T> &array, size_t index) {
    //This deleter works by holding on to the underlying array until the deleter itself is deleted.
    struct {
        boost::shared_array<T> array;
        void operator()(T *) {} //No action required here.
    } deleter = { array };
    return shared_ptr<T>(&array[index], deleter);
}
```

The next thing I'm going to try is upgrading to Boost 1.53.0 (we currently only have 1.50.0), using `shared_ptr<T[]>` instead of `shared_array<T>`, and also always using `boost` instead of `std` (even for non-arrays). I'm hoping this will then work, but I haven't had a chance to try it yet:

```
shared_ptr<int[]> array(new int[10]);
shared_ptr<int> element(array, &array[2]);
```

Of course I'd still prefer the instance method syntax, but I guess I'm out of luck with that one (short of modifying Boost):

```
shared_ptr<int> element = array.shared_ptr_to(2);
```

Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Your deleter idea is *the* way it should be done. There is nothing particularly inefficient in it (if in doubt, run an experiment with a profiler).

Comment: @n.m. I think it'll create a new control block (on the heap) for the new `shared_ptr` to refer to. Granted it's not that bad, but it's still better if it can share the same control block. :)

Comment: Do you need a `shared_array` at all? If you had a `shared_ptr<T>` (with appropriate deleter), you could use the aliasing constructors.

Comment: I've since thought about that. The only thing missing then is `operator[]`. I'll post an answer saying what I did in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing strange stuff.
Why do you need `shared_ptr` to element? Do you want element of array be passed somewhere else and hold down your array from removal?

If yes, than `std::vector<shared_ptr<T>>` is more suited for that. That solution is safe, standard and has fine granularity on objects removal

Comment: Yeah, I want the whole array to be kept as long as I have a pointer to any element. The kind of scenario this will happen in is when an API takes a shared_ptr for safety, but on occasion we allocate a lot of similar objects all at once, and want to minimise the amount of heap overhead. Meanwhile, the rest of the application doesn't particularly need to know that the objects came from an array. - Though, I think maybe weak_ptr is more suitable for these cases, but then of course all the above questions still apply, but with slight tweaks to say weak_ptr instead of shared_ptr in some places.

Comment: @entheh And what about array's lifetime, when would it be released?

Comment: Whichever object owns the shared_ptr to the array would be in charge of that. But for example, I might take weak_ptrs to elements sometimes and provide them to Lua, and there will always be someone who accidentally keeps an object around in Lua too long. We want defined behaviour when that happens, that's all. (I'm not sure if the shared_ptr-to-element case will come up for us.)

Answer (score 0):

`boost::shared_ptr` does not seem to support this nativly. Maybe you can work around this with a custom deleter. But `std::shared_ptr`  offers a special constructor to support what you want:

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    double b;
};

int main()
{
    auto sp1 = std::make_shared<foo>();
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp2 (sp1,&sp1->a);
}
```

Here, `sp1` and `sp2` share ownership of the `foo` object but `sp2` points to a member of it. If `sp1` is destroyed, the `foo` object will still be alive and `sp2` will still be valid.

Comment: Yeah, that's the aliasing constructor (and boost _does_ have it) :). Unfortunately, it will only take a `shared_ptr<anything>`, whereas I wanted to pass it a `shared_array<something>`.

Comment: It looks like Boost 1.53 and above have `shared_ptr<T[]>` (see the end of the introduction at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm); you might need to use that instead of `shared_array`, though, to use that specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in the end.

I made my own implementation of `shared_array<T>`. It effectively extends `shared_ptr<vector<T>>`, except it actually extends my own wrapper for `vector<T>` so that the user can't get the vector out. This means I can guarantee it won't be resized. Then I implemented the instance methods I needed - including `weak_ptr_to(size_t)` and of course `operator[]`.

My implementation uses `std::make_shared` to make the vector. So the vector allocates its internal array storage separately from the control block, but the vector itself becomes a member of the control block. It's therefore about equivalent to forgetting to use `std::make_shared` for a normal type - but because these are arrays, they're likely to be largeish and few, so it's less important.

I could also create an implementation that's based on `shared_ptr<T>` but with `default_delete<T[]>` or whatever is required, but it would have to allocate the array separately from the control block (so there's not much saving versus vector). I don't think there's a portable way to embed a dynamically sized array in the control block.

Or my implementation could be based on `boost::shared_array<T>`, and use the custom deleter when taking element pointers (as per the example in the question). That's probably worse in most cases, because instead of a one-time hit allocating the array, we get a hit every time we take an aliased pointer (which could happen a lot with very short-lived ones).

I think the only reasonable way to get it even more optimal would be to use the latest boost (if it works; I didn't get as far as trying it before I changed my mind, mainly because of the desire for my own instance members). And of course this means using the `boost` ones everywhere, even for single objects.

*But*, the main advantage with what I went with is Visual Studio's debugger is (I'm told) good at displaying the contents of std::shared_ptrs and std::vectors, and (we expect) less good at analysing the contents of boost things or custom things.

So I think what I've done is basically optimal. :)